# notification manager to start last open screen of the application

Tags: android, android-intent, notifications, android-pendingintent

Currently I am working on notification. But when I already receive notification and I have clicked on this notification on notification bar, I have not to open new activity. But I have to open recent activity. When some data have saved in my recently app and app running in the background and receive notification then using pending intent activity start with `onresume`/`oncrete`. But my last activity saved data has been lost. So  any solution when click on notification then I have  not to restart activity.

Please give me some solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: hello,i have solved my problem using set intent to setflags.
`Intent notificationIntent = null;
  notificationIntent = new Intent(mActivity, conductpd.class);
  notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
  notificationIntent.putExtra("MessageSender", chatHistory.getFromName());`

Comment: You can answer to your question and accept it :)

Comment: Means this problem has been solved with your self..?

Comment: yes..i have solved my problem myself.

Comment: @dipali...that's nice....Congrats...!!

Comment: but i have to face some other problem.when i have setflags in intent then i have send some message using putextra.but when i am retrieving intent using bundle then i get value of bundle is null

Comment: Are you using Bundle from where you are passing your data??

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36298/discussion-between-dipali-and-piyush-gupta)

Comment: So its getting perfect now??

Comment: no i am not getting perfect solution.getintent() not working.its always null.please give me some solution.

Comment: OK... let's continue with in chat room....

Comment: please code you share of put extra and getextra..

Comment: i have solved my problem...
`protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
  super.onNewIntent(intent);
  setIntent(intent);
 }
`

Comment: Oh...That's great....fine....Congrats....again.

Comment: Hello Dipali......Are you there?

Comment: yes......................

Comment: @dipali why are you not come with any chat room or on gmail... sometimes it is necessary...and someone need help also

Comment: @dipali  Please answer your own question and accept it, to get it off the list of unanswered questions.

Comment: @DavidWasser please put this line in when pending intent call:
notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

Comment: _+1_ here is the best solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31448840/android-how-to-open-last-activity-when-tapping-notification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got solution.

Add Flag in pending intent to clear top /recent activities from Stack,.

**`notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);`**

Comment: _+1_ here is the best solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31448840/android-how-to-open-last-activity-when-tapping-notification